# Java variable initialization?

Tags: java, literals

What is this type of initialization know as:

```
long i=12l;        //using 'l' to denote long variable
double d=12.0d;    //using 'd' to denote double variable
```

Is there a difference between:

```
long i=12l;
and    
long i=12L;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are just declaring and initializing a variable in the same statement, and using [literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10) to supply the initial values.

There's no difference between the two statements in the second snippet - except for readability. It's much easier to read "L" because it looks nothing like a "1". (One of the [Java Puzzlers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032133678X) is based on this - and apparently the whole book's font was chosen to make that puzzle even harder.)

Comment: I was reading Java puzzler's when i came across the uppercase literal.I just asked so as to make sure if they are same as lowercase literals.

Answer (score 1):

1. Definition and intialisation in the same statement
2. Yes, readability